# Name a copy of a Sheet the value in a cell in original sheet

Tags: excel, vba

This script loops through a file pathway and combines all workbooks into a master workbook and sections each workbook into a worksheet within the master file.

I have a line `ws.Name = activeworksheet.Range("B1").Value` that names the sheets as a copy of the first workbook's worksheet Sheet1 and names every sheet after that like Sheet1(2).

[image]

How can this be changed to the value in cell B1 of the workbook it is consolidating into the master workbook?

rest of script:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombineWorkbooks()

    Dim MainWB As Workbook
    Dim sDirPath As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    sDirPath = "M:\New folder"

    sFileName = Dir(sDirPath & "\*.xlsx")

    Set MainWB = ThisWorkbook

    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0

        sFilePath = sDirPath & "\" & sFileName

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFilePath)

        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            ws.Copy After:=MainWB.Sheets(MainWB.Sheets.Count)    
            ws.Name = activeworksheet.Range("B1").Value
        Next ws

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

        sFileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: change `activeworksheet` to `ActiveSheet`

Comment: @DisplayName it still keeps naming them as a copy of sheet1. Could it be the `For Each` loop where it's `ws.copy after:=mainwb.sheets`?

Comment: which cell in which worksheet of which workbook you want to name new worksheets after?

Comment: whatever sheet I grab from the folder. So I go in, grab the first workbook (sheet1) in that pathway, and whatever the value is in cell `B1` of that workbookwhat I want to name the worksheet as when it is moved to the `MainWb`

Comment: then `ActiveSheet.Name = ws.Range("B1").Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after `.Copy()` method of `Sheet` object, the newly created sheet becomes the *active* one, while `ws` still holds reference to the *original* sheet

so go like follows

```
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            ws.Copy After:=MainWB.Sheets(MainWB.Sheets.Count)

            ActiveSheet.Name = ws.Range("B1").Value
        Next
```

Comment: that worked! One last thing, what if I wanted `MainWB` to just be a brand new `Book1.xlsx`? 

Would that be `Set MainWB = Workbooks.Add`?

Comment: I guess so, but ...its' easy to test it yourself!